# What is the set notation for an image with data??

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to describe all data-points $x_i,...,x_n$ on a 2D digital image, say $X$. Each pixel is either background, or a datapoint. Is it possible to describe all of that as a set? I guess something like this where $k$ is meant to be a non-data pixel, but i'm not sure:

$$X = \{\{(x_i,x_j) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | i,j \neq k, k = 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$$

Answer (score 2):

An issue with trying to represent a 2D digital image with a set is that you lose information regarding the position of pixels relative to each other.

Even more, as you have it now, there is no way of determining the state of a pixel: how can we know if $(x_i, y_i)$ is a background pixel or a data pixel?

This is like trying to show someone what a fully-built lego set looks like by showing them a bag of pieces it's comprised of.

I'd say it'd be better if you represented your image with a matrix since, by definition, digital images *are* matrices with pixel elements.